# Is there an `install all` option?

Tags: delphi, build

In Delphi you have a `build all` option when building a project group.
[image]

However there is no `install all` option.
I have to select all the geared icons [image]
And choose <kbd>install</kbd> on each and every one of them.

**Is there a way to do this in one go?**

Comment: The Jedi Installer will compile and install all the packages.

Comment: @RobertLove, It's not a question about JEDI, it's a general question about project groups.

Comment: Just noticed the Jedi components that you have open in your screen shot.

Comment: The solution I go with is to select all the geared items and then pick [Install] from the context-menu. This will install all of them in turn (provided you did not miss one or accidentally clicked a wrong item)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently there is no option for that, but there is a QC entry:

Report No: 89593          Status: Reported
package group (project group with packages) "Install All" Option
http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=89593

Comment: Note that [QualityCentral has now been shut down](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/quality-keeps-moving-forward), so you can't access `qc.embarcadero.com` links anymore. If you need access to old QC data, look at [QCScraper](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/06/09/how-to-save-qualitycentral/).

Comment: @RemyLebeau, LOL